# Convert csv file to json dictionary

Tags: python, json, csv

i'm trying to convert a csv file to a json dictionary using python but i have zero experience to manipulating json file.

csv sample:

```
Picture         Class   Region_count    Coordinates
foto_1jpg.jpg   tennis        1         "all_points_x":[154,157,230,275,278,218,160,11...
foto_1jpg.jpg   soccer        2         "all_points_x":[446,557,685,795,826,815,738,62...
foto_1jpg.jpg   basket        3         "all_points_x":[941,1065,1161,1310,1438,1497,1...
foto_2jpg.jpg   soccer        1         "all_points_x":[331,403,518,626,688,734,758,681,...
foto_2jpg.jpg   basket        2         "all_points_x":[972,887,830,802,789,804,857,96...
```

I've converted the csv file with this code:

```
import csv 
import json 
 
def csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    jsonArray = []
      
    #read csv file
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
        #load csv file data using csv library's dictionary reader
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf) 
 
        #convert each csv row into python dict
        for row in csvReader: 
            #add this python dict to json array
            jsonArray.append(row)
  
    #convert python jsonArray to JSON String and write to file
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
        jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=4)
        jsonf.write(jsonString)
          
csvFilePath = r'/content/test_set.csv'
jsonFilePath = r'train.json'
csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

The results of this conversion is a json list that has this structure:

```
[
    {
        "Picture": "foto_1jpg.jpg",
        "Class": "tennis",
        "Region_count": "1",
        "Coordinates": "\"all_points_x\":[154,157,230,275,278,218,160,112,113,154],\"all_points_y\":[461,461,455,495,576,625,625,563,505,463]"
    },
    {
        "Picture": "foto_1jpg.jpg",
        "Class": "soccer",
        "Region_count": "2",
        "Coordinates": "\"all_points_x\":[446,557,685,795,826,815,738,628,505,422,346,331,354,443],\"all_points_y\":[230,186,212,321,411,538,641,687,684,632,525,426,331,224]"
    },
    {
        "Picture": "foto_2jpg.jpg",
        "Class": "soccer",
        "Region_count": "1",
        "Coordinates": "all_points_x:[331,403,518,626,688,734,758,681,594,484,369,314,282,274,329],\"all_points_y\":[399,340,316,342,380,463,607,736,787,796,745,683,592,503,405]"
    }
]
```

My goal is to obtain a json dictionary that has this structure:

```
{"foto_1jpg.jpg121349":
  {"filename":"foto_1jpg.jpg","regions":[
    {"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[154,157,230,275,278,218,160,112,113,154],"all_points_y":[461,461,455,495,576,625,625,563,505,463]},"region_attributes":{"name":"tennis"}},
    {"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[446,557,685,795,826,815,738,628,505,422,346,331,354,443],"all_points_y":[230,186,212,321,411,538,641,687,684,632,525,426,331,224]},"region_attributes":{"name":"soccer"}},
    {"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[941,1065,1161,1310,1438,1497,1509,1471,1382,1279,1124,998,916,874,847,874,938],"all_points_y":[132,44,26,48,144,266,396,514,628,673,687,631,560,479,328,233,135]},"region_attributes":{"name":"basket"}}],"file_attributes":{}},
"foto_2.jpg325912":
 {"filename":"foto_2.jpg","regions":[
   {"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[331,403,518,626,688,734,758,681,594,484,369,314,282,274,329],"all_points_y":[399,340,316,342,380,463,607,736,787,796,745,683,592,503,405]},"region_attributes":{"name":"soccer"}},
   {"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[1186,1233,1273,1282,1267,1231,1178,1154,1135,1131,1142,1182],"all_points_y":[921,921,891,845,806,777,775,789,819,859,895,919]},"region_attributes":{"name":"tennis"}}],"file_attributes":{}}
```

I've tried to insert the key 'Region' into the json file with this code:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
 
def ctree():
    
    return defaultdict(ctree)
 
def build_leaf(name, leaf):
    res = {"Picture": name}
    if len(leaf.keys()) :
      res["Region"] = [build_leaf(k, v) for  k, v in leaf.items()]
    return res
 
def main():
    tree = ctree()
    
    with open('/content/templete.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for rid, row in enumerate(reader):
            if rid == 0:
                continue
            leaf = tree[row[0]]
            for cid in range(1, len(row)):
                leaf = leaf[row[cid]]
    res = []
    for name, leaf in tree.items():
        res.append(build_leaf(name, leaf))
 
    import json
    return json.dumps(res)
main()
```

The result was a big fat failure:

```
[
{"Picture": "foto_1jpg.jpg", "Region": [
  {"Picture": "tennis", "Region": [{"Picture": "1", "Region": [{"Picture": "\"all_points_x\":[154,157,230,275,278,218,160,112,113,154],\"all_points_y\":[461,461,455,495,576,625,625,563,505,463]"}]}]},
  {"Picture": "soccer", "Region": [{"Picture": "2", "Region": [{"Picture": "\"all_points_x\":[446,557,685,795,826,815,738,628,505,422,346,331,354,443],\"all_points_y\":[230,186,212,321,411,538,641,687,684,632,525,426,331,224]"}]}]},
  {"Picture": "basket", "Region": [{"Picture": "3", "Region": [{"Picture": "\"all_points_x\":[941,1065,1161,1310,1438,1497,1509,1471,1382,1279,1124,998,916,874,847,874,938],\"all_points_y\":[132,44,26,48,144,266,396,514,628,673,687,631,560,479,328,233,135]"}]}]}]}
```

How can I reach my goal structure?

Thanks for the attention

Comment: Could you please add a sample of the csv file?

Comment: i have updated the question with the csv sample!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for convert in json VIA:

```
import csv, json

li = []
with open('/content/file.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        li.append({
            "filename": row['Picture'],
            "region": {
                "shape_attributes":{
                    "name":"polygon",
                    "Coordinates": row['Coordinates'],
                    "region_attribute":{
                        "name": row['Class']}}}})
with open("file.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(li, f, indent=4)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I went into the same problem as I wanted to generate a JSON to be serialized and consumed by a REST API which expects a list - not a string containing a list.

I found a solution that is agnostic of the CSV file structure and the columns. This is done in three steps: read the CSV, evaluate the expression contained in each row, and export to JSON.

First, you read the CSV with `DictReader`:

```
for row in csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=";"):
  ...
```

To evaluate the rows, you use the `ast` module (Abstract Syntax). Readapting the snippet found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/71137896/10966677, and simplifying it for the use case of JSON format:

```
import ast

def literal_eval(source):
    # Adapted from `ast.literal_eval`
    def _convert(node):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Constant):
            return node.value
        if isinstance(node, ast.List):
            return list(map(_convert, node.elts))
        if isinstance(node, ast.Dict):
            return dict(zip(map(_convert, node.keys), map(_convert, node.values)))
        if isinstance(node, ast.Expression):
            return _convert(node.body)
        if isinstance(node, ast.Name):
            return ast.get_source_segment(source, node)
        raise ValueError('element cannot be parsed for a valid json')

    return _convert(ast.parse(source, mode='eval'))
```

This function will properly evaluate lists or dictionaries. For example, the row read from `DictReader` is:

```
row = {'nb_simulations': '10000', 'units': '5000.0',
       'alpha': '[0.5, 0.95, 0.99, 0.999]',
       'method': 'sim'}
```

To evaluate the string `'[0.5, 0.95, 0.99, 0.999]'` as a list:

```
dict((k, literal_eval(v)) for k, v in row.items())
# prints: {'nb_simulations': 10000, 'units': 7000.0, 
#   'alpha': [0.5, 0.95, 0.99, 0.999], 'method': 'sim'}
```

Using all this in the code:

```
import csv, json

result = []
# read from CSV file
with open(csv_file, encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for row in csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=";"):
        result.append(dict((k, literal_eval(v)) for k, v in row.items()))

# write to JSON file
with open(json_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    json.dump(result, file, indent=4)
```

This works also with lists and dictionaries nested into each other.

Example CSV:

```
nb_simulations;units;alpha;method;rating
10000;1000.0;[0.5, 0.95, 0.99, 0.999];sim;{'type': 'A', 'scores': [1, 10]}
10000;2000.0;[0.5, 0.95, 0.99, 0.999];calc;{'type': 'A', 'scores': [2, 20]}
10000;3000.0;[0.5, 0.95, 0.99, 0.999];calc;{'type': 'B', 'scores': [3, 30]}
```

Example JSON output:

```
[
    {
        "nb_simulations": 10000,
        "units": 1000.0,
        "alpha": [
            0.5,
            0.95,
            0.99,
            0.999
        ],
        "method": "sim",
        "rating": {
            "type": "A",
            "scores": [
                1,
                10
            ]
        }
    },
...
```

And it is independent of the columns or structure of the input.